# Change DIV background image depending on which menu item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with class jumbotron that has a background image.

I also have a menu of 6 items.

I want to use javascript or jQuery to change the jumbotron's background image depending on which menu item was clicked. Each menu item has it's own unique image I'd like to replace as .jumbotron's background image.

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">    

</div>

           <ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Item 1</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Item 3</a></li>     
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Item 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Item 6</a></li>
            </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url(../images/item1.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `css` `:target`, `<img>` elements

```css
.jumbotron {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.jumbotron img {
  width: calc(100vw);
  height: calc(100vh);
}

.jumbotron :not(:target) {
  display: none;
}

img:target {
  display: block;
}

.nav,
.jumbotron {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats" id="cats">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports" id="sports">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/animals" id="animals">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/nature" id="nature">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/abstract" id="abstract">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/city" id="city">
</div>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#cats" data-toggle="tab">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#sports" data-toggle="tab">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#animals" data-toggle="tab">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#nature" data-toggle="tab">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#abstract" data-toggle="tab">Item 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#city" data-toggle="tab">Item 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the path to the image in a data attribute, read that in on click, and assign it as the background image of the element.

```js
$('.nav-tabs a').on('click',function(e) {
  var bg = $(this).attr('data-bg');
  $('.jumbotron').css('background-image','url('+bg+')');
})
```

```css
.jumbotron {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: 0 0 no-repeat / cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron"></div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-bg="http://cdn.thedailybeast.com/content/dailybeast/articles/2015/03/31/neil-degrasse-tyson-defends-scientology-and-the-bush-administration-s-science-record/jcr:content/image.img.2000.jpg/1432067001553.cached.jpg">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-bg="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-bg="http://public.media.smithsonianmag.com/legacy_blog/npg_portraits_nicholson_jack_2002.jpg">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a click handler for each of the elements, when they're clicked change the background image.

If you want to use some other information about the tabs, I might add some `data` attributes which can be referenced (i.e. what you need for the URL).

```js
$(".nav.nav-tabs li a").click(function(){
  $(".jumbotron").css("background-image", "url('"+$(this).data("url")+"')");
});
```

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url(../images/item1.jpg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron">    

</div>

           <ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-url="../images/item1.jpg">Item 1</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-url="../images/item2.jpg">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-url="../images/item3.jpg">Item 3</a></li>     
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-url="../images/item4.jpg">Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-url="../images/item5.jpg">Item 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-url="../images/item6.jpg">Item 6</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd capture the `click` event for the nav container with jQuery, and depending on the specific clicked element, associate the `background-image` property for the `.jumbotron` element.

In other words:

```js
$('.jumbotron').click(function() {
  var target = $(this).attr('id');
  var background;
  
  switch (target) {
    case 'someId-1':
      background = 'some-url';
      break;
    case 'someId-2':
      background = 'some-url';
      break;
    case 'someId-3':
      background = 'some-url';
      break;
    case 'someId-4':
      background = 'some-url';
      break;
    case 'someId-5':
      background = 'some-url';
      break;
    case 'someId-6':
      background = 'some-url';
      break;
  }
  
  $('.jumbotron').css('background-image', 'url(' + background + ')')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron">    

</div>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
    <li><a href="#" id="someId-1" data-toggle="tab">Item 1</a></li>   
    <li><a href="#" id="someId-2" data-toggle="tab">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="someId-3" data-toggle="tab">Item 3</a></li>     
    <li><a href="#" id="someId-4" data-toggle="tab">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="someId-5" data-toggle="tab">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="someId-6" data-toggle="tab">Item 6</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Another option would be to define different CSS classes for each image, and toggle one or another depending on which link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Nice 'n easy. Just swap a CSS class. You can later edit the css to change pic size, position, actual image, without touching code.

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
.btnOne {
     background-image: url('obi.jpg');
}
.btnTwo {
     background-image: url('luke.jpg');
}
.picStyle {
     width: 75px;
     height: 75px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="btn1" onclick="changeIt ( this )">Button 1</div>
<div id="btn2" onclick="changeIt ( this )">Button 2</div>
<div id="pic" class="btnOne picStyle"></div>

<script>

function changeIt ( elem ) {
    let pic = document.getElementById ( 'pic' );
    if ( elem.id === 'btn1' ) {
        pic.classList = [ 'btnOne', 'picStyle' ];
    } else {
        pic.classList = [ 'btnTwo', 'picStyle' ];
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you name your images item1, item2 and so on, the following will work:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[data-toggle]", function() {
  var background = $(this).text().replace(" ", "").toLowerCase();
  alert(background);
  $(".jumbotron").css("background-image", 'url(../images/' + background + '.jpg)');
})
```